# html file browsing in java

Tags: java, swing, html-parsing, awt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [display HTML page the same in Java forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540998/display-html-page-the-same-in-java-forms)

I want to display a HTML file in Java Swing application. I am using the following code, it displays the specified URL web page but I want to display a static HTML page stored on a particular location eg `D:\\new folder\test.html`. How is it possible? Is there any other useful tool in Swing than JEditorpane?

I am using the following code

```
try {
    URL url= new URL("http://www.lawcrux.com");
    htmlPane = new JEditorPane();
    htmlPane.setContentType("text/html");
    htmlPane.setPage(url);
    htmlPane.addHyperlinkListener(this);

    JScrollPane jsp= new JScrollPane(htmlPane);

    cp.add(jsp);
    jsp.setBounds(750, 50, 600, 600);  
} catch(Exception ex) {}
```

Comment: *"I want to display a static HTML page stored on a particular location eg D:\\new folder\test.html. How is it possible?"* As an aside, the answer to this was provided in the last 2 lines of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12540795/418556) on one of your **duplicate** threads under your **split** personality.  *If you don't intend reading the answers, please stop asking the questions.*  :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
File htmlFile = new File("c:/web.html");
htmlPane.setPage(htmlFile.toURI().toURL());
```